# getting Error "Request method eth_chainId is not supported" on new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

Tags: ethers.js

On initialisation `new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(<any>window.ethereum, "any");`

Everything works fine but cannot get rid of this error.
Error stack says the error comes from @ethersproject/providers

version: "ethers": "5.7.2"

Does any one had same issue or have any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue, if any one will struggle trying to get rid of this annoying console error: you could manually set the chain id and network name as second param of `Web3Provider`

```
this.networkSettings = {
                name: this.network,
                chainId: this.chainId
            };
this.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(<any>window.ethereum, this.networkSettings);
```

Link to the comment that was helpful - https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1293#issuecomment-636203902